# Copy Excel template in another template with pictures

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I try to merge two Excel templates together in C#. Everything works fine except for the pictures in the second template that aren't merged.

I use the following steps to achieve my objective :

1. Load the first template
2. Add content to the first template
3. Load the second template
4. Copy the template's content in the clipboard
5. Paste the clipboard's content in the current `Worksheet`

Sadly, I have no control over the templates themselves as they are provided by the client and I can't change them.

Here's the code :

```
public static void MergeTemplates()
{
    ExcelApp app = new ExcelApp();
    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    app.Workbooks.Open($"{path}\\Excel1.xltx", true);
    var workbook = app.Workbooks[1];
    var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
    sheet.Range["A1"].Value = "Sometext";

    //Loading the second template, which has images.
    var xlTemp = app.Workbooks.Open($"{path}\\Excel2.xltx", true);
    var xlSheetTemp = xlTemp.Worksheets[1];

    xlSheetTemp.Range["A1", "C10"].Copy();

    //Add the second template at the end of the first
    sheet.Range["A2","C11"].PasteSpecial();

    xlTemp.Close();

    workbook.SaveAs($"{path}\\Test.xlsx");
    workbook.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

At the end, the images of `Excel2.xltx` aren't imported in the saved `Test.xlsx` document.

How can I merge the two templates so that the images will be included?

Comment: The images are recognized as shapes I am pretty sure. Something like xlSheetTemp.Shapes[picture_name].Copy()

Comment: foreach(shape in xlSheetTemp.Shapes) { shape.copy(); }

Comment: Indeed, I had to copy/paste each image invidually. It's a kinda lame way to do it though. Thanks for the info though

Comment: If that helped and you used it as the answer, do you mind if I go ahead and write it as the answer to the question? That way if someone searches they will be able to use this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony Guertin Yeah sure go ahead!